# Inserting some zeros in a list by a rule of positions

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:

```
mainlist={0.23, 0.34, 0.8, 0.0, -0.2, 0.4, -0.1};
```

I have to extend the above list to another one `finalresult` with `Length=17`. But in `finalresult`  the elements of the `mainlist` must be in the positions ruled by the `positionlist`:

```
positionlist={3,4,8,9,10,13,14};

finalresult={0,0,0.23,0.34,0,0,0,0.8,0.0,-0.2,0,0,0.4,-0.1,0,0,0}
```

How can I reach this goal?  I would be so glad to see an answer.

Comment: I expect somebody to reference a duplicate, but you can use `finalresult = ConstantArray[0, 17]; finalresult[[positionlist]]=mainlist` in the meantime.

Comment: Related: [(30339)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30339/121), [(30647)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30647/121), [(31648)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31648/121), [(41877)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41877/121), [(147876)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/147876/121)

Comment: @CarlWoll I looked but I was unable to find a duplicate.  Perhaps you would care to convert your comment to an answer, in the mean time. :^)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Normal@SparseArray[Thread[positionlist -> mainlist], 17, 0]
```

**Update**: should emphasize *C.E.*'s nice comment:

```
Normal@SparseArray[positionlist -> mainlist, 17]
```

equivalent in result, more pleasantly laconic, and lack of explicit thread  actually less expensive for longer lists.

Comment: +1. `Thread` and the zero at the end can be omitted.

Comment: A usage note regarding the performance of this method: [(148112)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148112/121)

Answer (score 7):

```
mainlist={0.23, 0.34, 0.8, 0.0, -0.2, 0.4, -0.1};
positionlist={3,4,8,9,10,13,14};

ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, 17], Thread[positionlist -> mainlist]]
```

or what @Carl Woll suggested:

```
finalresult = ConstantArray[0, 17];
finalresult[[positionlist]] = mainlist
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {0.23, 0.34, 0.8, 0.0, -0.2, 0.4, -0.1};

p = {3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14};
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
SubsetMap[list &, Table[0, 17], p]
```

{0, 0, 0.23, 0.34, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0., -0.2, 0, 0, 0.4, -0.1, 0, 0, 0}

Answer (score 2):

**Using `Fold`:**

```
Clear["Global`"];
mainlist = {0.23, 0.34, 0.8, 0.0, -0.2, 0.4, -0.1};
positionlist = {3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14};

rules = Rule @@@ Transpose[{positionlist, mainlist}];
Fold[ReplacePart[#1, #2] &, Table[0, 17], rules]
```

> {0, 0, 0.23, 0.34, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0., -0.2, 0, 0, 0.4, -0.1, 0, 0, 0}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {0.23, 0.34, 0.8, 0.0, -0.2, 0.4, -0.1};

p = {3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14};
```

An alternative using `Cases` and `If`:

```
rep = Rule @@@ Thread[{p, list}];

Cases[Range[17], x_ :> If[And @@ (Unequal[x, #] & /@ p), 0, x /. rep]]

(*{0, 0, 0.23, 0.34, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0., -0.2, 0, 0, 0.4, -0.1, 0, 0, 0}*)
```